# Ionic 3 - Pan Events

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I can't find any documentation on Pan events in Ionic 3, or if they are coming from Cordova or Angular 4?

```
<div class="swipper" #swipper (panleft)="swipe( $event)" (panright)="swipe( $event)" (panend)="swipe( $event) " (panup)="swipe( $event) " (pandown)="swipe( $event) ">
```

The panup and pandown events do not get fired all the time and generally very really sticky or even buggy (Testing in Chrome and the iOS Emulator). So as a solution I'm thinking of using touchstart touchend events instead, which would require a rewrite but first I would like to know a bit more about the pan events.

Answer (score 2):

It is there. Here you can see [**the doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures).

> Basic gestures can be accessed from HTML by binding to tap, press,
>   pan, swipe, rotate, and pinch events.

Sample from [**official code base**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/gestures/basic/template.html):

```
<ion-card (pan)="panEvent($event)">
<ion-item>
  Panned: {{pan}} times
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Still though, they don't mention anyway panleft/panright/panend for example